# iPhone - Playing badformat 3gp file using MPMoviePlayerController is not giving error

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using `MPMoviePlayerController` to play few videos.

But unfortunately, one of the video whose extention is 3gp is in bad format.
On click of a button, the video is played and using some calculation, different videos are selected.

When the badly formatted video is selected its displaying a message "The movie format is not supported" which I don't want to show. I want to select another video if the format of video is wrong.

I implemented "`MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification`". I'm handling error condition as well as successfull condition. Why am I not receiving error in this notification when the video format is wrong?